# getting javascript/typescript error "Cannot read property 'Items' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, express, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'Items' of undefined" in javascript. `this` keyword is always `undefined` in the `Base` class.

how to resolve this issue? Is there any issue with `static` method to use in `express` router?

Typescript compile option is pointing to `ES6`.

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction, Wrap } from '../../../Core';
import {FacadeRequest} from '../../../Common';

class Base {
    public Items: any = { Name: 'Natarajan Ganapathi' };
    public Get(): any {
        return this.Items;
    }
}

class User extends Base {
    public GetUsers(): any {
        return super.Get();
    }
}

export type BoRegistry = { [key: string]: () => any };

export class Facade {
    public static BoRegistry: BoRegistry = {};
    public static async GetData(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<any> {
        let promises: Array<any> = [];
        let reqs = req.body as Array<FacadeRequest>;
        reqs.forEach(fReq => {
            let route = Facade.ParseRoute(fReq.Route);
            let func = Facade.BoRegistry[route.BoName];
            if (!func) {
                throw new Error(route.BoName + ' not register in BoRegistry');
            }
            let bo = func();
            promises.push(Facade.Invoke(bo, route, fReq));
        });
        return await Promise.all(promises);
    }

    private static async Invoke(bo: any, route: { BoName: string, MethodName: string }, fReq: FacadeRequest): Promise<any> {
        let api = bo[route.MethodName];
        if (!api) {
            throw new Error(route.MethodName + ' is not available in ' + route.BoName);
        }
        let res = await api(fReq.Request);
        return { [fReq.Key]: res };
    }

    private static ParseRoute(route: string): { BoName: string, MethodName: string } {
        let r = route.split('/');
        if (r.length < 2 || r.length > 2) {
            throw new Error('Request contains improper route');
        }
        return { BoName: r[0], MethodName: r[1] };
    }
}

Facade.BoRegistry['User'] = () => new User();

let router: Router = express.Router();
router.post('/' + Facade.GetData.name, Wrap(Facade.GetData));
export default router;
```

```
{
"Message": "Cannot read property 'Items' of undefined",
"Stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Items' of undefined\n    
at Get (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:17:20)\n    
at GetUsers (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:22:22)\n    
at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:48:29)\n    
at next (native)\n    at __awaiter (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:7:65)\n    
at __awaiter (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:3:12)\n    
at Function.Invoke (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:43:16)\n    
at Base.static.GetData.reqs.forEach.fReq (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:37:38)\n    
at Array.forEach (native)\n    
at /Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:30:18\n    
at next (native)\n    at __awaiter (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:7:65)\n    
at __awaiter (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:3:12)\n    
at GetData (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Modules/Base/Router/Facade.js:27:16)\n    
at exports.Wrap (/Users/dist/dev/Server/Core/Core.js:70:16)\n    
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/node_modules/router/lib/layer.js:93:5)"
 }
```

Comment: Can you show where you're actually calling GetUsers? I see you instantiating a User, but never using this method.

Comment: Adding to what ndugger said, the value of `this` in Javascript depends on how you call your methods so its important to show the call sites too.

Comment: I am calling `GetUsers` from `Invoke` method. line  `let res = await api(fReq.Request);`

Answer (score 0):

> "Cannot read property 'Items' of undefined",

Common JavaScript error. You need to be cautions of your usage of `this` or just use an arrow function.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html